# Load h3-js in <script> tags and use it in vanilla html file

Tags: javascript

I want to try out this [library h3-geo](https://h3geo.org/docs/installation).

I created a simple file to load the library:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Land</title>

  <!--
    <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    -->
  <style>
    #Karte {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Karte"></div>
</body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/h3-js/index.js"></script>

<script>
  var Karte = L.map("Karte").setView([40.7577369, -73.9911839], 15);
  L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    attribution: 'Kartendaten &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    useCache: true,
  }).addTo(Karte);
</script>

</html>
```

I tried to load it via [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/h3-js/3.4.3) and also trying to load the node package, which gives me the following error:

[image]

Any suggestions why the library is not loading correctly?

Do I really need to start a react app to try it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is because the file is a CJS module designed run using Node.js. While there are tools (like Webpack) which can de-modulify code for running in the browser, they won't work here because "being a module" isn't the only part of this code that depends on Node.js.

(React applications are typically built using webpack, but writing your entire application in React is overkill if you just want to deal with modules.)

The module you are trying to use is a set of bindings over a library written in C.

It makes use of Node.js APIs to access the compiled C library. Browsers do not provide similar APIS.

You cannot run this in a web browser.

Either:

- Write your program entirely in Node.js
- Use Node.js (or Python or Java since they also have modules fo H3) to create a web service that uses this module and then access it with Ajax